# Jquery Fullcalendar event background image per day

Tags: jquery, laravel, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using jquery fullcalendar.
I am going to render events in year view of calendar.
What I want is to set background image per event day.
[image]

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
  eventElement.find("div.fc-content").addClass("fc-background");
},
```

I did like above but background image was displayed per week.
Is there any better solution?

Comment: eventRender executes per _event_, not per day. This year view must be a custom add-on, it's not part of the core fullCalendar, so it's not certain how it would behave, but in theory it should respond to the [dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayRender) callback. That gives you access to each day, rather than each event.

Comment: P.S. I removed the "fullcalendar-4" tag, because you are clearly using an earlier version - fullCalendar 4 doesn't use jQuery and its eventRender callback has a different signature. I'll assume you're using v3, but if it's even earlier than that please say so.

Comment: Yes I think I am using v3.  * FullCalendar v0.0.0 Stylesheet
 * Docs & License: https://fullcalendar.io/
 * (c) 2017 Adam Shaw  This is what I saw in fullcalendar.css file.